# Make a jpeg in a Twilio MMS redirect to a website when pressed

Tags: php, twilio

I am sending a JPEG image in a Twilio MMS message and I want that image to redirect to a website when touched/pressed by the customer on his/her cell phone.

Is this possible to do with Twilio? If so, how?

Comment: While I believe this can technically be done using SMIL markup I am not sure if this is supported by Twilio.

Comment: I can see deleted questions and comments, so I see that you are trying to emulate ZipRecruiters messages. Is the message they send just a link and your phone is producing an image preview of the site?

Comment: Cleaned up title and asked the implicit question explicitly